# Reading a line that starts with a hash on a .txt file

Tags: r, file, hash

The first line of my .txt file looks like that:

> `#` 12 0.44 0.001 0.94444 123.3455 0.0000001 3432.0 2 1 1 12.2

It is a space separated numerical values but the issue is that the line starts with a hash.

**Is there any way I can read this first line from R even though it starts with a hash** (without having to modify the file)**?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try `scan`.  The comment character indicator `comment.char` is turned off by default. And you can add `nlines = 1` to get only the first line from the file.

```
x <- "# 12 0.44 0.001 0.94444 123.3455 0.0000001 3432.0 2 1 1 12.2"
as.numeric(scan(text = x, what = "", nlines = 1)[-1])
# Read 12 items
#  [1]   12.0000000    0.4400000    0.0010000    0.9444400  123.3455000
#  [6]    0.0000001 3432.0000000    2.0000000    1.0000000    1.0000000
# [11]   12.2000000
```

So it should be okay if you replace `text = x` with your file name.

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Thanks a lot. I replaced `text = x` by `text = readLines(path/to/file, n=1)` for my specific case. +1

Comment: @Remi.b - glad to help, but did you try just putting your file name in there?  It should work too as `scan` reads directly from file.  `scan(filename, what="", nlines=1)`

Comment: Oh I didn't get that. However, it fails when I just enter `text = "path/to/folder/filename.txt"`. It just returns `"path/to/folder/filename.txt"`

Comment: @Remi.b - don't write `text =`.  Instead make it `file =`

Answer (score 3):

If you change the comment indicator option to something not in your text file it should load:

```
mydat <- read.table('test.txt', comment.char = '&', header = FALSE)
```

This assumes you don't have any lines that you *want* to prevent from loading with a hash at the start.

Edit: The reason you need to change comment.char being that the default is #